# Bit build throws an error if a component uses external library like Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, bit.dev

My use case:

I have a Button component with Material UI. I want to export that component to bit component, but while compiling the `bit build`, I get an error on Material UI  modules:

[image: error screenshot]

How do I isolate a component if it has external library dependencies?

Comment: HI and welcome to stackoverflow!  Best practice is to include the error text in the body of your question, rather than as a picture.  (Check out this post for a full discussion of the reasons why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 2):

You can reference dependencies (and peerDependencies) in the "workspace.jsonc" file like this:

```js
"teambit.dependencies/dependency-resolver": {
  "packageManager": "teambit.dependencies/pnpm",
  "policy": {
    "dependencies": {
      "@angular/router": "13.0.3",
      "@ngrx/effects": "13.0.1",
      "@ngrx/store": "13.0.1",
      "@ngx-translate/core": "14.0.0"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {}
  }
},
```

[Here](https://harmony-docs.bit.dev/building-with-bit/manage-workspace/#dependency-resolution) is the documentation.

Certain use cases need "[Compositions](https://harmony-docs.bit.dev/aspects/compositions/#creating-compositions)" to use building blocks in isolation, mocking how a component would function in a project.